# Filter rows on patterns and position in column

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I need help with this task. I have a dataframe with speaker `id`s and their `speech` in conversations:

```
df <- data.frame(
  line = 1:10,
  id = c("A", "A", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  speech = c("hi", "how are you [Larry]?", "[uh]", "(0.123)", "I'm fine [you 'n Mary] how's it [goin]?", "[erm]", "(0.401)", "well", "(0.555)", "y'know what it's like")
)
```

I need to `group_by` speaker `id` and then `filter` those rows where the `first` element in `speech` matches the pattern `[...]`. The last item filtered should match the pattern `(...)`; anything further down (in the same group by the same `id`) should *not* be filtered.

The desired output is this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
   line id    speech   grp
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <int>
1     3 B     [uh]       2
2     6 B     [erm]      5
3     7 B     (0.401)    5
```

I've tried this (which filters too little):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\[.*?\\]$", first(speech)))
```

And I've tried this (which filters too much):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\[.*?\\]$", first(speech)) & !grepl("^\\(\\d\\.\\d{3})$|^\\w+", speech))
```

Comment: Oh that's a mistake! Thanks so much for spotting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function which returns the row number to subset from each group and apply it for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

return_rows <- function(x) {
  if(grepl('\\[.*\\]', x[1]) && length(x) > 1) return(1:grep('\\(.*\\)', x)[1])
  else return(0)
}

df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(return_rows(speech))

#   line id    speech 
#  <int> <chr> <chr>  
#1     3 B     [uh]   
#2     6 B     [erm]  
#3     7 B     (0.401)
```

`return_rows` function checks if the first value has the pattern `[...]`, if it does and length of the value is greater than 1 then it returns value from 1 to the row number where the pattern `(...)` is present. If `[...]` isn't present then it returns 0 meaning no rows are selected of that group.

---

To consider every consecutive occurrence of `id` as separate group we can use `rleid`.

```
df %>% group_by(group = data.table::rleid(id)) %>% slice(return_rows(speech))
```

Comment: The function can accommodate several consecutive `[...]`, right?

Comment: In the same group? No. If the first value has `[...]` it will returns rows from row 1 to the first  `(...)`.

Comment: But in the actual data set there are cases where in the same group there are 1-4 `[...]`. And with the actual data set the code does not work: it fails to pick up on the `(...)`values.

Comment: I've checked: in `df` your code works perfectly even if there are multiple consecutive `[...]` in the same group. Can the code be set up not with `group_by(id)` but with `group_by(grp = rleid(id))`?

Comment: Yes, that change with `rleid` should work. Should I edit the answer with it?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: Sorry, this causes an error: `Error in 1:grep("\\(.*\\)", x)[1] : NA/NaN argument
Called from: return_rows(speech)`

Comment: I have updated the function for that. Also if you want to use `group_by(grp = rleid(id))` your expected output need to be changed for that.

Comment: It's not **always** that there are multiple `[...]`, so the condition `&& length(x) > 1`is too narrow. But the main problem is with the transfer of the code to my actual dataset: here neither function (neither the initial nor the updated one) catch the `(...)` values and I can't seem to see why ...